# create a list from duplicated data in columns in the same dataframe in RStudio

Tags: r

I have several columns in the same data frame that lists location names, but the column headings differ slightly

1. Location 1 (Adelaide, Sydney, Perth)
2. Location 2 (Perth, Darwin, Adelaide)
3. Location 3 (Brisbane, Adelaide, Melbourne)

I want to get one location column that combines all three of these columns but only keeps unique location names.

For example, my final column list would be - Location (Adelaide, Sydney, Perth, Darwin, Brisbane, Melbourne)

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example of your data frame?

Comment: +-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Location1 | Location2 | Location3 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Adelaide  | Perth     | Brisbane  |
| Sydney    | Darwin    | Adelaide  |
| Melbourne | Adelaide  | Melbourne |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+

Comment: There is nothing RStudio-specific in this question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
newcol<-with(yourdf,unique(c(Location1,Location2,Location3)))
```

Comment: thank you, unfortunately this seems to return a number (count) instead of the location name?

Comment: You need to convert factor columns into character in this case.

Comment: Just wondering if you are able to help with another level of complexity for this question, say for every location column there is also a country column, ie location 1, country 1, location 2, country 2, etc....do you know how i would firstly, test if each location is unique to one country, or if say two different countries had the same location name, and then collate these unique location-country matches into one output data set? - which may have location names duplicated in rows if they have different countries - hope this makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

If those are in a dataframe then thei gives you a reduced factor result,

```
> unique(unlist(dat))
[1] Adelaide  Sydney    Perth     Darwin    Brisbane  Melbourne
Levels: Adelaide Perth Sydney Darwin Brisbane Melbourne
```

Which if you wanted as a dataframe is simple enough:

```
newdat <- data.frame(Location1 = unique(unlist(dat)) )
> newdat
  Location1
1  Adelaide
2    Sydney
3     Perth
4    Darwin
5  Brisbane
6 Melbourne
```

And `as.character` could turn it into a character vector.

Test object:

```
dat <- data.frame(
     Location1 = c('Adelaide', 'Sydney', 'Perth'),
     Location2= c('Perth', 'Darwin', 'Adelaide'),
     Location3 =c('Brisbane', 'Adelaide', 'Melbourne'))
```